# Install Puppy Linux or "Damn Small Linux" on Pogoplug (~NSLU2) possible

Tags: system-installation, puppy-linux, dsl

I am thinking about buying Pogoplug (50 $) which is in fact a NAS server similar to the famous `nslu2`. Like the `nslu2`, this device can be hacked to have a full fresh Linux server running. There are lots of tutorials on how to install Linux and `LAMP` to turn it into a web server. [Check here](http://lifehacker.com/5637092/turn-a-pogoplug-into-a-fully+featured-linux-web-server)

**My question is if Pogoplug is able to run Linux, is it then possible to install Puppy Linux (or with live USB) with the graphical user interface?**

I ask this because I don't know if there is a graphics board inside.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you done *any* research on your own?

Comment: [Have a look here, for example.](http://plugcomputer.org/plugwiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: @sr_ not answering my question but thanks for the interesting link. rational and functional solution for a low power pc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no graphics card in the pogo plug so if you wish to use a graphical installer then the answer is no ...

But you can still use the tutorials you have found and use ssh to log in to it and work from/with/on the plug itself if that is interesting.

Comment: Theoretically one could even run a GUI program on a Pogo using a separate machine with an X server. Not sure if the OP wanted that :)